# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user... - mysql shell works

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

After a failed Wordpress upgrade I got the error

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user...

So I reinstalled WP, but still getting the same error. The strange thing is I can connect to the mysql server (remote host) via the mysql shell (on the same PHP server), just not via PHP. So doesn't seem to be a credentials/firewall issue.

I tried it with a separate script with only the `mysqli_connect()`, but also no luck. I replaced the server host name with an IP, also did not work.

PHP: 7.0

Edit: It turned out that the mysql server required a ssl connection, so I had to add `define('MYSQL_CLIENT_FLAGS', MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);`
 to `wp-config.php`.

Comment: You should upgrade as soon as possible. This version of PHP hasn't been supported for few years.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem at one stage. My fix came when i added the port extension to my localhost. Like this:

```
mysqli_connect(localhost:3307, "root", "", "$db_name").
```

Try and establish which port your statement is attempting to make a connection with.
3308, 3307, 3306

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately that did not help. Such a weird issue.

Comment: This is wrong answer. The host should be enclosed in quotes and the port should be passed in the fifth parameter.